# Display unicode characters in Java

Tags: java, unicode

I tried to display some unicode characters in the range Sinhala (80: 0D80–0DFF) in java swing components. Those letters are displayed correctly in eclipse console, but those are shown as boxs in JButtons , JTextArea, JTextPane & etc.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Unicode extends JFrame{

    public Unicode(){

        super("ක් කැ කැ කු අ ඉ");

        add(new JButton("ක් කැ කැ කු අ ඉ \u0D88"),BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(new JTextField("ක් කැ කැ කු අ ඉ"), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setSize(500,500);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String a[]){
        new Unicode();
    }
 }
```

I tried to display by using characters and character codes, but neither works. Many answers given by the google doesn't work. Please give me a help. I'm using windows 7 with java 1.6.

Thank you...

Comment: Check your font.

Comment: it's better to have unicode chars in "\uXXXX" format, so you are save and do not depend on source file encoding or font. But even better have all the string in a property file.

Comment: My Swing rule: Square boxes = Font problem, Question marks = Encoding problem.

Comment: @Alexery: i tried with \uXXX format but it didn't worked.

Comment: @SLaks: But eclipse console shows the correct font without any changes to the font and even notepad shows correctly.

Comment: @maamaa Eclipse does not use Swing; it uses SWT as its widget kit. Swing uses the JRE logical fonts by default. This looks like a font-substitution issue in the Swing implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If eclipse is able to render sinhala fonts, then it is for sure that you have fontfile that has sinhala glyphs. Now swing component is not able to pick that font up so you need to explicitly enforce to pick that file to display.

So as to make generalize solution, you need to iterate over code pages and have to find which supports sinhala range of unicodes.

Please have look at this link for more info:

http://content.hccfl.edu/pollock/Java/Fonts.htm

Answer (score 2):

Please set Font that "IskolaPotha".
I think it work properly.(I used this font). but Swing componetns(without JFrame) dose not display "ක්‍යෝ"unicode chars properly.